# TModLoader seems to not let me build my mod, with error CS1061

Tags: c#, .net, rider

I was making a Terraria mod in TModLoader, and I got this error.

```cs
using Terraria;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace FastPickaxe.Items
{
    public class FastPickaxe : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetStaticDefaults()
        {
            DisplayName.SetDefault("Sixty-Nine Thousand Four Hundred Twenty times 2 Pickaxe");
            Tooltip.SetDefault("Even the Damage is worth it! Hopefully your PC won't crash...");
        }


        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            item.damage = 69420;
            item.melee = true;
            item.width = 64;
            item.height = 64;
            item.useTime = 2;
            item.useAnimation = 10;
            item.pick = 69420;
            item.useStyle = 1;
            item.knockBack = 2;
            item.value = 10000;
            item.rare = 13;
            item.UseSound = SoundID.Item1;
            item.autoReuse = true;
        }

        public override void AddRecipes()
        {
            ModRecipe recipe = new ModRecipe(mod);
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.LifeCrystal, 99);
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.LifeFruit, 99);
            recipe.AddTile(412);
            recipe.SetResult(this);
            recipe.AddRecipe();
        }
    }
}
```

What happened here? I did define the variable for LocalizedText, but what's going on?
The error says:

> Compiling FastPickaxe.dll failed with 18 errors and 0 warnings, Error CS1061: 'Localized Text' does not contain a set definition for 'SetDefault' and no accessible extension method 'SetDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'Localized Text' could be found.
> TModLoader Version 2023.9.3.3
> Terraria 1.4.4.9

I asked the Bing AI to fix the code, but it said that it was right. Could it be possible that this isn't working correctly?

I'm using .NET 6.0.0
with JetBrains Rider.